# Issue when adding PDF viewer appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android

When I use this code:

```
compile'com.github.barteks.android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2-beta.4'
```

I get this error:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018.
>   For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   Failed to resolve: com.github.barteks.android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2:
>   Open File

How can I resolve this?

Comment: compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace compile with:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteks.android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2-beta.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is asking you to use implementation instead of compile but that is not the cause of your error.

You should be using 2.8.2 and not 2.8.2-beta.4. It's possible the beta versions of the library have been removed from jcenter. If the beta versions are still available, it's possible that you have not configured build.gradle to search jcenter. If you have, then it means that the library is unavailable there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It work for me by using older version of sdk, I use `sdk 26`, and appcompat `v7:26+`.